# Formatting frontmatter pages

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, line-spacing, scrbook

I am finalizing my master's thesis. Among the frontmatter elements, there are pages for the *Copyright statement*, *Acknowledgements*, and *Abstract*.

I have **two** issues that I couldn't manage to solve:

1. How to suppress the page numbering (as well as the headline and footline) in the *Abstract* page? I have used `\thispagestyle{empty}` for this page as I did for *Acknowledgements*, but it didn't take any effects ONLY in *Abstract*. (WHY?)
2. How to make the `\begin{doublespacing}` and `begin{doublespacing}` work in both *Abstract* and *Acknowledgements*? (Currently they seem not taking any effects either...)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,twoside,fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=12mm,DIV=12,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook} % two-sided


\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}


% --- Copyright statement ---
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
Copyright \textcopyright\ 2022 (MY NAME) All rights reserved.

% --- Acknowledgements ---
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\vspace*{20mm}

\begin{center}
    \usekomafont{disposition}
    {\Large Acknowledgements}
\end{center}

\vspace*{10mm}

\begin{doublespacing}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{doublespacing}

% --- Abstract ---
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\vspace*{20mm}

\begin{center}
    \usekomafont{disposition}
    {\Large Abstract}
\end{center}

\vspace*{10mm}

\begin{doublespacing}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{doublespacing}

% --- Table of contents ---
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
    \tableofcontents
}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}
% Turns off page numbering for 'Table of Contents'
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% Body of text
\blinddocument


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}` only affects the *current* page.  If you want to make this page and the next ones empty, use `\pagestyle{empty}` and then later on, switch back to the default with `\pagestyle{headings}`  (I *think* that is the default for `scrbook`.)

Comment: @Thruston Yes, I think in the cases I want `\thispagestyle{empty}` to be applied on the **current** pages, which are *Acknowledgements* and *Abstract* page, respectively. But I don't understand why it doesn't work on the *Abstract* page... (But on the *Acknowledgements* page, it works though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than keep repeating `\thispagestyle{empty}` on each page you that you want without headers and footers, a simpler approach might be to structure your document like this

```
\documentclass[...]{scrbook}
... preamble..
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

... blank stuff ...

\newpage
\pagestyle{headings}

... rest of the document

\end{document}
```

The thing to bear in mind in that `\pagestyle` comes into effect at the *next* time TeX breaks a page.

However `scrbook` class already a couple of macros that help you group front matter and main matter, so I think my preferred structure would be like this

```
\documentclass[...]{scrbook}
... preamble..
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}

... blank stuff ...

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{headings}

... rest of the document

\end{document}
```

These `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` macros take care of the page numbering properly.

☞ As for the missing double spacing, I think that's a feature of `lipsum`.  If you put real text in there, you should find it double spaces properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the text within a `doublespacing` environment should end with a blank line for it all to work.

```
\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,twoside,fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=12mm,DIV=12,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook} % two-sided


\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{comment}
% --- Copyright statement ---
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
Copyright \textcopyright\ 2022 (MY NAME) All rights reserved.

\end{comment}

% --- Acknowledgements ---
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\vspace*{20mm}

\begin{center}
    \usekomafont{disposition}
    {\Large Acknowledgements}
\end{center}

\vspace*{10mm}

\begin{doublespacing}
  \lipsum[1]
  
\end{doublespacing}

% --- Abstract ---
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\vspace*{20mm}

\begin{center}
    \usekomafont{disposition}
    {\Large Abstract}
\end{center}

\vspace*{10mm}

\begin{doublespacing}
  \lipsum[1]
  
\end{doublespacing}

This is after the doublespacing, so it should show the regular interlinear
spacing. Does it? Take a look and see what you think.

\end{document}
```

I haven't checked but perhaps the `singlespace` and `onehalfspace`environments also require a blank line before the `\end{...`.